# django how to post data from a function into an other function?

Tags: python, django, function, post

There is 2 html divs in index.html, green and red.

I want when I click on
each of these divs, the `/result` page appears with the message `you have choosed {{ color }} div`.

How should I edit this:

```
        return render(request, 'result.html', {'color': })
```

How I can POST data from a function in a page into an other function in an nter page?

How I can send the color of each div into result page by clicking on the dive?

views.py;

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def colors(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')

def result(request):
    return render(request, 'result.html', {'color': })
```

base.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#green {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:lightgreen;
}
#red {
    margin-top:5px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

result.html:

```
you have choosed {{ color }} div
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from secondv.views import hello, colors, result 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^index/', colors),
    url(r'^result/', result),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I found the answer myself.

base.html should be changed as these:

```
<a href="/result?q=green"> <div id='green'></div> </a>

<a href="/result?q=red"> <div id='red'></div> </a>
```

And views.py should be changed like this:

```
def result(request):
if 'q' in request.GET:
    color = request.GET['q']
return render(request, 'result.html', {'color': color})
```